# Parse ObjectID not getting stored in Event class swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to save an object id of the event created. I have tried both async and sync save and saving the object id in a variable. but I am not able to access the value of object id from other classes but i am able to access other variables from the event class

```
class Event: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var userImage:UIImage!
var userName:String!
var creatoruserName:String!
var segueIdenifier:String!
var eventId:String!
....
 func addToDB() {
    let event = PFObject(className:"Event")
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    event["createdBy"] = currentUser
    event["eventType"] = self.eventType
    event["eventAttributes"] = attributes
    event["eventDate"] = time
    event["locationDescription"] = locationAsString

    if (locationAsPoint != nil){
        event["Location"] = locationAsPoint


         try! event.save()
         self.eventId = event.objectId!

        print("objectId1 \(eventId!)")
        print("objectId2 \(self.eventId!)")

         try! event.save()
    //            event.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
//                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
//                if (success) {
//                    print("event created")
//                    // The object has been saved.
//                    print("event.objectId! \(event.objectId!)")
//                    self.eventId = event.objectId!
//                    temp_objectId = event.objectId!
//                    print("self.objectId! \(self.eventId!)")
////                    event.seteventID((event.objectId)!)
//                    
//                } else {
//                    // There was a problem, check error.description
//                }
//            }
        }

 //       print("objectId1 \(self.objectId!)")

}
```

I the values of objectId1 is getting printed when this function is called . 
when i am passing this from segue it is not printing the value of objectid.
what am i missing?

```
if (segue.identifier == "findOutMore") {
    let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! CustomProfileViewController;
    svc.event = self.eventSelected
    print ("event id1 is  \(eventSelected.geteventID())")
```

it prints nil coz i have made geteventID that if the value is nil put " " in it.

Comment: What is the implementation of `geteventID` ?  Why are you using the eventId instead of the PFObject itself?

Comment: you are write. I used the wrong implementation of geteventID.before I was using    self.eventId = event["objectId"] as! String so it was giving nil value but that is wrong. Now I am using like   self.eventId = event.objectId! as! String and it works. Took me too long to figure it out.